# No change after translate all CSV files

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, shopping-cart, csv, inline-translations

I would like to output another name instead of `"Cart"` or "My Cart" on my Magento store. So here is what I did, I went to the `app/locale/en_US` folder and changed `"Cart","My custom name", "Add to Cart","Add to My custom name"` and so on.

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why and provide me with a solution or somewhere to look?

Comment: where did you edit the content?

Comment: Like I said, everywhere I saw the words `Cart` or `My cart` on all CSV files present at the folder `app/locale/en_US`

Comment: is en_US selected as locale?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I am not sure. Can you explain better?

Comment: Have you set default locale for your store view

Comment: Got it, Now I know what happened, thanks so very much!

Comment: The Locale setting in System > Configuration > General > Locale Options. But I see from your answer below that you found it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After very helpful feedback and some Googling I Found out that the issue was being caused by my Locale definitions. Because the store is located in Sweden I had previously configured Sweden as Locale but not added any Swedish language.

Therefore, I was still experiencing the store in English which led me into a wrong conclusion after updating the CSV files. Everything worked as it should after I updated my Locale settings.

Thank you very much!